# Explain code in C

Tags: c, linux, shell, code-analysis

I wanna understand this code specially the parse_args. This code is as simple shell to run the basic linux command as pwd cat and so on. I wanna understand how parse_args works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1<<16
#define ARR_SIZE 1<<16

void parse_args(char *buffer, char** args, 
                size_t args_size, size_t *nargs)
{
    char *buf_args[args_size]; /* You need C99 */
    char **cp;
    char *wbuf;
    size_t i, j;

    wbuf=buffer;
    buf_args[0]=buffer; 
    args[0] =buffer;

    for(cp=buf_args; (*cp=strsep(&wbuf, " \n\t")) != NULL ;){
        if ((*cp != '\0') && (++cp >= &buf_args[args_size]))
            break;
    }

    for (j=i=0; buf_args[i]!=NULL; i++){
        if(strlen(buf_args[i])>0)
            args[j++]=buf_args[i];
    }

    *nargs=j;
    args[j]=NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]){
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char *args[ARR_SIZE];

    int *ret_status;
    size_t nargs;
    pid_t pid;

    while(1){
        printf("$ ");
        fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
        parse_args(buffer, args, ARR_SIZE, &nargs); 

        if (nargs==0) continue;
        if (!strcmp(args[0], "exit" )) exit(0);       
        pid = fork();
        if (pid){
            printf("Waiting for child (%d)\n", pid);
            pid = wait(ret_status);
            printf("Child (%d) finished\n", pid);
        } else {
            if( execvp(args[0], args)) {
                puts(strerror(errno));
                exit(127);
            }
        }
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What in particular don't you understand

Comment: what did you find out so far?

Comment: This question belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @icepack: I don't think it really belongs on CodeReview.  It is not asking for how to improve it; it is asking for an explanation of what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this section of code

```
for(cp=buf_args; (*cp=strsep(&wbuf, " \n\t")) != NULL ;){
        if ((*cp != '\0') && (++cp >= &buf_args[args_size]))
            break;
 }
```

check the wbuf array for " \n\t" delimiters (first is space) and save its positions in buf_args
then in

```
for (j=i=0; buf_args[i]!=NULL; i++){
        if(strlen(buf_args[i])>0)
            args[j++]=buf_args[i];
    }
```

section exrtacting the arguments into args array to have the result out of the function

Answer (score 4):

That's fun. The function separates buffer to an array of strings, where it hits a white-space delimiter.

```
void parse_args(char *buffer, char** args, 
                size_t args_size, size_t *nargs)
{
    char *buf_args[args_size]; /* You need C99 */
    char **cp;
    char *wbuf;
    size_t i, j;
```

Initialization code...

```
    wbuf=buffer;
    buf_args[0]=buffer; 
    args[0] =buffer;
```

Set all  pointers to the beginning of the buffer

```
    for(cp=buf_args; (*cp=strsep(&wbuf, " \n\t")) != NULL ;){
```

1. Set the write pointer `cp` to point to the first element in the buf_args array.
2. Set *cp to the next instance of a non-whitespace token in the buffer, and advance `wbuf` to its ending position

   ```
       if ((*cp != '\0') && (++cp >= &buf_args[args_size]))
           break;
   ```

Stop when `strsep` returned NULL, or when it points to the end of the buffer, or when it points beyond the end of buf_args[]

```
    }

    for (j=i=0; buf_args[i]!=NULL; i++){
        if(strlen(buf_args[i])>0)
            args[j++]=buf_args[i];
    }
```

This loop creates a condensed copy of the buf_args[] array: it copies only the arguments which aren't empty strings. I guess that could happen if your source buffer had a series of consecutive white-space characters.

```
    *nargs=j;
    args[j]=NULL;
}
```

Put a NULL at the end of the output array and set the `nargs` output argument.

Comment: could you explain exactly what strsep , strlen       for example i insert this command ls -al how these two function will work

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so let's walk through some of the lines in parse args

```
wbuf=buffer;
buf_args[0]=buffer; 
args[0] =buffer;
```

This sets `wbuf` to point to what is in the `buffer`. It also sets the first pointer in the array of `buf_args` to the `buffer`. And it does the same thing for the first element of `args` as well.

```
for(cp=buf_args; (*cp=strsep(&wbuf, " \n\t")) != NULL ;){
    if ((*cp != '\0') && (++cp >= &buf_args[args_size]))
        break;
}
```

The function `strsep` looks through `wbuf` for the delimiters space, newline or tab and returns a pointer to the begining of a token, with `wbuf` updated to the end of the token. If there are no more delimiters in the string, the function returns `NULL`. So, the middle part of the `for` statement continues until `*cp` equals `NULL`.

So, the pointer `cp` initially points to the string (pointer) in `buf_args[0]`. The string separator function fills `*cp` with the address of the token. Then, the `if` statement check 1) if the `for` loop has exceeded the capacity of `buf_args`, by checking whether the pointer `cp` has exceeded the last element and 2) if the first character of the returned token is the end of string character.

Note: I think that line should be `*(*cp) != '\0'`?

```
for (j=i=0; buf_args[i]!=NULL; i++){
    if(strlen(buf_args[i])>0)
        args[j++]=buf_args[i];
}
```

Then, it loops over all the `buf_args` until it finds a `NULL` one. If the string pointed to by `buf_args` is longer than 0, i.e. it has characters, the array `args` gets a copy of the pointer to the token.

```
*nargs=j;
args[j]=NULL;
```

The last element of `args` after the filled entries is set to `NULL`. And the value of `nargs` is set to the length of the number of filled elements in the `args` array.

Comment: The `*cp != '\0'` condition might just be a funny way of writing `*cp != NULL` (it is equivalent to that).  `'\0'` is a null pointer constant, but not a usual one.

Comment: I understand that, but it is weird to mix notation like that in a single program.